Amazon AppFlow not giving options for filters
I'm creating a new flow. The source is an S3 folder containing a CSV file The destination is another S3 folder in the same bucket. The source file just contains a few columns all of type string. I would like to add a filter for one of my columns but I get the following message on the filter's screen. Is there any reason why I am not able to add filters.

